# What is the meaning of っていう here?

Tags: grammar, particle-と

Context is two high school students are casually discussing preparing for college entrance exams next year.

> 来年受験か? 家庭教師とか頼まなきゃいけないかな～
>
> 私家庭教師したことあるよ．近所の男の子が受験だっていうから私見てあげてたんだよ. 家庭教師できるなら受験も楽勝だよね

I'm familiar with という(っていう) being used for something being said <s>and also as an abstract way to describe something (ウィル・スミスがあるという映画)</s>. I don't think the usage here is the former grammar since everything before the っていう does not sound how someone would talk to her. I also don't think it's the latter grammar since that takes a noun after という, but here it is から.

I think she's saying "The boy(s) in my neighborhood was taking entrance exams, so I looked over him". If that is the case, can you help me understand っていう in the sentence? And how would it be different to a sentence without it:

> 近所の男の子受験だから私見てあげてたんだよ

Comment: There seems to be several typos in your quoted lines. 私家庭教師しことある or 私家庭教師し**た**ことある? 近所の男の子が受だっていうから or 近所の男の子受**験**だっていうから

Comment: @EddieKal Thanks for catching that, fixed

Comment: What do you think ウィル・スミスがあるという映画 means?

Comment: Do these answer your question? [Sentence-ending という](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/72253/5010) / [what is the difference between である ＆ という](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33563/5010)

Comment: @aguijonazo Movies starring Will Smith

Comment: @naruto Somewhat. It sounds like という goes beyond just being things said and can be used for general hearsay if an apt meaning is "I had heard the boy(s) in my neighborhood was taking entrance exams, so I looked over him". If that is so, is there a reason という isn't conjugated into a form so that it makes sense for it to be "I had heard" like といったから or いってから?

Comment: No, it doesn't mean that. If I have to make some sense out of it, I would understand it as “*a movie Will Smith says exists*” or “*a movie Will Smith says something exists in*,” which makes little sense.

Comment: @hulapoll1 I think という as a special construction doesn't conjugate exactly because it's a special construction. Compare 近所にIKEAができ**た**ので行ってみた, 近所にIKEAができた**という**ので行ってみた and 娘が近所にIKEAができたと教えてくれ**た**ので行ってみた.

Comment: @naruto I would say the first has nothing to do with hearsay, this new IKEA was recently finished recently so you tried going. The second is you heard/got information somehow that IKEA was recently finished so you tried going. And the third has a more concrete feeling of "That women informed me of the recently finished IKEA, so I tried going. So in that sense, という felt like a more off-hand way to say "i hear it (from somewhere probably unspecified and could maybe be implied or deduced?)".
Anyway hearing という as a special construction that doesn't conjugate satisfies what I was curious about.

Comment: @hulapoll1 Perfect. Do you mind if this this question is flagged as a duplicate of the abovementioned questions?

Comment: By all means go ahead