# What「というか」at the end of sentence mean?

Tags: grammar

The below is a dialogue with translation by a person chilling with a friend under beautiful weather.

> 落ち着くといいますか... 時間がゆっくりといいますか
>
> I feel like I can relax... it's like time itself is taking it easy

I don't understand the role of「というか」in these sentences. I'm not sure if I'm overthinking or not. The [jisho](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%81%8B) definition doesn't fit this context because there are two「というか」s. Judging from the translation, can「というか」is used to describe speaker's feelings?

Comment: This might answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/57621/ending-sentences-with-%e3%81%a8%e3%81%84%e3%81%86%e3%81%8b-%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%81%86%e3%81%8b

Comment: @flowsnake Thanks, it helped. It's weird that this question doesn't appear when I first searched for というか in this SE.

Comment: It was quite far down, so understandable