# What is the role of というか at the beginning of sentence?

Tags: grammar, colloquial-language

Context: A and B are in relationship. A was drunk from hangover. B helped A to get in to his house. A realized that B entered his house once again. He thought

> っていうかBがまた...

I'm not sure what というか is doing here. I checked this [answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/57621/ending-sentences-with-%e3%81%a8%e3%81%84%e3%81%86%e3%81%8b-%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%81%86%e3%81%8b). It only discusses the function of というか at the end of a sentence. I don't know if it mean the same thing when placed at the beginning of a sentence.

My take: I think というか at the beginning functions similar to ゆうのは. It means something like "I mean." Am I right here?

Comment: You've not provided much context, but my guess would be that it's just a shortened version of something like なんっていうかBがまた.  **A** seems to be saying "what's this?  B['s back] again?"  Where more context might be helpful, it seems to me that **A** is a bit annoyed that **B** is back again, which, if that's the case, I might translate what **A**'s saying as "what the hell!  B again??"

Comment: @A.Ellett I don't think A is annoyed. He likes having B in his house. But, I think you are probably right to interpret というか as なんっていうか. Not sure if there are other ways to understand this expression.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- というか
- っていうか
- ってか, てか
- とゆーか, とゆうか, とゆっか
- ってゆーか, ってゆうか, ってゆっか
- ちゅーか, ちゅうか
- つーか, つうか, っつうか
- つか, っつか

These are all variants of というか. They have many roles.

- Used to make the sentence less certain: "kind of", "kinda", "sorta", "maybe"

  > まあ和食は好きっていうか。
  > Yeah, I kinda like Japanese cuisine.
- Used to rephrase or correct previous sentences (in an uncertain way): "or maybe", "maybe", "rather"

  > 試験はうまく行かなかった。というか、落ちた。
  > The exam did not go well. Or rather, I failed.
  >
  > っていうか、本当は分かってるんでしょー？
  > But you know that already, don't you?
- Used to interrupt the current conversation and change the topic to a more important/urgent one: "by the way", "whatever", "anyway", "wait"

  > つーか、この部屋暑くない？
  > By the way, isn't this room hot?
  >
  > つか、揺れてる？ 地震？
  > Wait, is it shaking? Earthquake?
- Used as a meaningless filler: "er", "well", "I mean", "you know"

  > ってゆっかてゆっかー、私って結構さみしがり屋っていうかー、だから、なんてゆっかー、ほら。
  > I mean, well, I'm kinda a lonely person, so I mean, I guess...you know.

You have provided no previous context, so it could be #2, #3 or #4 above.