# What does "っていうのか" mean?

Tags: particle-って

I am reading through the transcript of Madoka Magica episode 5 and I got to the line "何だか私、夢遊病っていうのか。" What does the "っていうのか" do to "夢遊病"?

A translation given is "Apparently, I went sleepwalking or some such thing..." which is not clearing things up for me much. I am assuming that "っていうのか" is the "or some such thing" part? Is that what it means exactly or are there other things it can imply?

Comment: Dup https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/85962/

Comment: Or perhaps does this answer your question? [About っていうか&っていうの&っていうんだ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/55641/about-%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%81%86%e3%81%8b%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%81%86%e3%81%ae%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%81%86%e3%82%93%e3%81%a0)

Comment: @A.Ellett That question is about っていうのか as a rhetorical question.

Comment: @naruto I hadn't thought of it as rhetorical anything.  But isn't that what's going on here to?  It's not a real question, just a question to oneself.  Right?  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @A.Ellett No, this use corresponds to the first example in Jimmy's link (和食は好きっていうか). She does think she is like 夢遊病.

Comment: @naruto I guess I don't understand the difference between the two.  :-(

Comment: See the first example [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/85967/5010). This っていうのか is a softener ("something like", "maybe", "kinda like", "or some such thing", "dunno how to put this but..."). @A.Ellett Something like 何がどう夢遊病だっていうのか would have been a rhetorical question (i.e., she is saying she is *not* sleepwalking). But in this sentence, she is saying she *is* somehow like sleepwalking.