# How should I understand って in 「っていねえし」?

Tags: grammar, colloquial-language, particle-って

When I first heard 「っていねえし」 or similar phrases used as an expression of surprise when the speaker finds their intended audience is not there any more or doesn't exist to begin with, I thought it was 「でいねえし」, で (それで/そこで) meaning "so" or "well". But it seems to be って.

> 「すみませーん。クラスメート熱あるみたいで…っていねえし」
> 保健室についたが人気が感じられない。([source](https://www.pixiv.net/novel/show.php?id=14385916))

> 「ま、いいかぁ。じゃ、とどめを‥‥っていねえし」([source](https://www.pixiv.net/novel/show.php?id=16415722))

If it's quotative and the contraction of と, can I understand it as coming from one of these:

> ○○と言ったところで人は(もう)いないことに気付いた

> ○○と言ったところ、人は(もう)いないことに気付いた

> ○○と言いたいが、気が付くと、人は(もう)いないし

> ○○と言っているけど、気が付くと、人は(もう)いないし

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of って is a distinct phrase used when a conversation or a plan was unexpectedly interrupted by something urgent. It's like "wait", "um" or "oh".

- それで昨日ね……って、聞いてる？
  And yesterday... Wait, are you listening?
- これを買って……って、3万円!? 高っ!
  I'll buy this and...what, 30,000 yen!? So expensive!

None of the dictionaries I checked explains this usage, but I also suppose this derived from the quotative-って used at the beginning of a sentence. Perhaps something like と言いつつ ("while saying this; meanwhile") or [と言うか](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/85967/5010) was shortened to って.