# Need help breaking down some grammar

Tags: grammar, meaning, translation

In a script I'm translating, Character A is telling Character B how Character C isn't afraid of performing difficult stunts. A proceeds to say:

> ……多少は危ないことに危機感を持ってほしいというか、あの無謀さは少々どうかと思う時もあるが——

I have a couple of questions about the grammar.

First, the というか. I'm not sure how the か fits in this sentence. My first guess is that A is paraphrasing what B said. Something like "He said something about..."

Second, is どうか, When I look it up, I get nothing that would make sense in this context. Am I forgetting something that would fit here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- というか is almost a word on its own, and it often has very little substantial meaning. In this case, it's used like "or rather", "or maybe" or "I mean". A is trying to paraphrase what A just said. See the second usage in my answer here: [What is the role of というか at the beginning of sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/85962/5010)
- どうかと思う means "(I) wonder how (it is)" or "it makes me wonder (what I can say about it)", but it should be memorized as a set phrase that euphemistically suggests someone/something is questionable. See [this dictionary entry](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%8B%E3%81%A8%E6%80%9D%E3%81%86).

> ……多少は危ないことに危機感を持ってほしい**というか**、あの無謀さは少々どうかと思う時もあるが——
>
> ...I do wish [C] had some sense of danger about risky things, **I mean**, there are times when I think that recklessness [of C] is a bit too much...