# カメラっていうかさ… meaning of ていう

Tags: grammar

For the sentence: カメラっていうかさ

What does ていう mean?

Comment: Do you have more context? Possibly related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/57621/ending-sentences-with-%e3%81%a8%e3%81%84%e3%81%86%e3%81%8b-%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%81%86%e3%81%8b

Comment: This is a heavily context-dependent expression. Provide more context if you're still unsure. Maybe it's like "Camera, maybe, but ...", "Not a camera but ...", "Enough about cameras, um, ...", etc.

Answer (score -3):

ていう means "kinda thing" or "looks like" so my guess is that your sentence fragment means "a cover for something like a camera"

Comment: ん？　`cover` はどこから？

Comment: @Chocolate - かさ（傘）？